# Python: How can I concatenate in a bytearray as I do with strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, pyserial

I would  like to get part of a bytearray from a string or int but Python gives me an error.

I tried this calling `sendfallblatt.self(1,02)` as those code are selected in GUI with a combolist of texts linked to numbers.

```
    sendfallblatt(fallblattadresse, fallblattcode):

        # <BREAK> FF <COMMAND> <ADDR> < VALUE> 

        ComPort = serial.Serial('COM5')                 # open COM5
        ComPort.baudrate = 19200                # set Baud rate to 9600
        ComPort.bytesize = 8                    # Number of data bits = 8
        ComPort.parity   = 'N'                  # No parity
        ComPort.stopbits = 1                    # Number of Stop bits = 1
        
        data = bytearray(b'\xff\xc0\x0' + str(fallblattadresse) + '\x' + str(fallblattcode))
        print(data)
        
        ComPort.send_break(0.06)
        ComPort.write(data)
        ComPort.close()
```

And I was expecting to get :

```
data = bytearray(b'\xff\xc0\x01\x02')
```

`fallblattadresse` are from 0 to 7 and `fallblattcode` are from 0 to 61 so I know I will be having à problem after 9 but I will be solving that later...

Thanks for your help as I'm not finding anything useful on the internet and I'm probably missing some basic knowledge about bytes handling.

Comment: what is `fallblattadresse`? Why do you try to convert that to a `str` but then concatenate that with `bytes`? `bytes` and `str` cannot be concatenated.  You can concatenate `bytes` with `bytearray` though

Comment: `b'abc' + b'def'` works just fine. Your problem is not all the things you're trying to concatenate are bytes. Some of them are bytes and others are strings.

Comment: @ThePhoton to be pedantic, they have `bytes` which are a distinct type from `bytearray` but compatible for concatenation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you're right but 'bytes' is a horrible term to make a plural out of. If you have two of them are they byteses?

Comment: @ThePhoton you have two `bytes` objects :)

Comment: Shouldn't `sendfallblatt.self` be `self.sendfallblatt`?

Comment: And if this is a method in a class, it needs `self` at the beginning of the parameter list. If it's an ordinary function, you don't put `.self` at the end of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the representation of a byte array (which uses `\x` to show hex codes) and the actual byte values. You don't get a byte array by concatenating the string representations. You can use the `bytes()` function to create a byte array from a sequence of numeric byte values.

```
fallblattadresse, fallblattcode = 1, 2
data = bytearray(b'\xff\xc0' + bytes((fallblattadresse, fallblattcode)))
print(data)
```

prints

```
bytearray(b'\xff\xc0\x01\x02')
```

Unless you need to modify `data` after the concatenation, you don't need to convert it to a `bytearray`.